# Apache doesn't start when there's a preloaded file

Tags: php, apache, php-7.4

I just installed `Opcache` and everything seems working just fine, but when I add a PHP file in `opcache.preload` in `php.ini` and restart the Apache server doesn't start. On the other hand, In CLI SAPI preloading works fine!

*When I comment out `opcache.preload` and restart, the Apache server works*

Since this issue is not emitting any error I looked up Apache `error_log` file and it turns out the issue was me not defining the opcahe preload user

> Fatal Error "opcache.preload_user" has not been defined

But according to [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php#ini.opcache.preload-user)

> Preloading code as root is not allowed for security reasons. This directive facilitates to let the preloading to be run as another user.

I'm working on my personal computer running Ubuntu under [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux)

**So please guide me what should I do? what user should I add?**

Comment: Are you sure using php7.4-fpm for apache2?

Comment: I am not sure, but that was a reason on my server php (for apache) was not working at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default user for web servers on Ubuntu is `www-data`

All you need to do is

```
opcache.preload_user=www-data
```

And if you want to check preloading

```
var_dump(opcache_get_status()['preload_statistics']);
```

It will list all preloaded files as well as the memory consumed by them

**As for why Apache refuses to start when I don't define a preload user?**

I actually don't know why. It might be a bug, not sure though.

---

While the statement from PHP documentation is not complete, but note that:

> Preloading under root **is not allowed by default**, but **explicit**
> use of opcache.preload_user=root is allowed
>
> - [Nikic](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=78894)